# Report Builder 3.0 - grouping rows by time of day

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to create a table within a report that appears as follows:

[image: Target Table]

The data set is based on this query:

```
SELECT 
DATENAME(dw, CurrentReadTime) AS 'DAY', 
DATEPART(dw, CurrentReadTime) AS 'DOW', 
CAST(datename(HH, CurrentReadTime) as int) AS 'HOD', 
AVG([Difference]) AS 'AVG'
FROM 
Consumption
INNER JOIN Readings ON Readings.[RadioID-Hex] = Consumption.[RadioID-Hex]
WHERE 
CONCAT([Building], ' ', [Apt]) = @ServiceLocation
GROUP BY
CurrentReadTime
ORDER BY 
DATEPART(DW, CurrentReadTime), 
CAST(DATENAME(HH, CurrentReadTime) AS INT)
```

The data from this table returns as follows:

[image: Data Results]

In report builder, I have added this code to the report properties:

```
Function GetRangeValueByHour(ByVal Hour As Integer) As String
Select Case Hour
Case  6 To 12
GetRangeValueByHour = "Morning"
Case 12 to 17
GetRangeValueByHour = "Afternoon"
Case 17 to 22
GetRangeValueByHour = "Evening"
Case Else 
GetRangeValueByHour = "Overnight"
End Select
Return GetRangeValueByHour
End Function
```

And this code to the "row group":

```
=Code.GetRangeValueByHour(Fields!HOD.Value)
```

When I execute the report, selecting the parameter for the target service location, I get this result:

[image: Actual Result]

As you will notice, the "Time of Day" is displaying the first result that meets the CASE expression in the Report Properties code; however, I confirmed that ALL "HOD" (stored as an integer) are being grouped together by doing a SUM on this result.

Furthermore, the actual table values (.05, .08, etc) are only returning the results for the HOD that first meets the requirements of the CASE statement in the VB code.

These are the things I need resolved, but can't figure out:

- Why isn't the Report Properties VB code displaying "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening", and "Overnight" in the Time of Day column?
- How do I group together the values in the table? So that the AVG would actually be the sum of each AVG for all hours within the designated range and day of week (6-12, 12-18, etc on Monday, Tuesday etc).

To those still reading, thanks for your assistance! Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Are you using a table or matrix? Are you using the row group expression (`=Code.GetRangeValueByHour(Fields!HOD.Value)`) for the Time of Day column?

Comment: I am using a table. The code in the report properties is being called on in the Time of Day column to group "Morning", "Afternoon", etc. 

I ended up changing the parameters for "Time of Day" to create (4) six hour periods. Then simply multiplying the values returned in the query by 6 in order to get the number I needed. 

That said, if you have a solution to the original question, I am still very interested in hearing how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if I have a clear picture of your table design, but I'm imagining this as a single row group that's grouped on this expression: `=Code.GetRangeValueByHour(Fields!HOD.Value)`.  Based on this design and the dataset above, here's how I would solve your two questions:

- Use the grouping expression for the value of the Time of Day cell, like:

[image: Expression for Time of Day column]

- Add a `SUM` with a conditional for the values on each day of the week.  Example: the expression for Sunday would be `=SUM(IIF(Fields!DOW.Value = 1, Fields!AVG.Value, CDec(0)))`.  This uses `CDec(0)`instead of 0 because the AVG values are decimals and SSRS will otherwise throw an aggregate of mixed data types error by interpreting 0 as an int.